# AxesLabel in a phase plot in the BodePlot command

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I've the following code:

```
BodePlot[{1/(((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(1.\
6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*(56000 + 
          56000)*((56000*56000)/(56000 + 56000)))*(2*Pi*f*
         I)^3 + ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(\
56000)*(56000 + 
           56000) + \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(1.6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*(56000 + 
           56000))*(2*Pi*f*
         I)^2 + ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000) + \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000 + 56000 + 56000))*(2*Pi*f*I) + 
     1)}, {f, 0, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{"Linear", "dB"}, {"Linear", "Degree"}}]
```

It creates two plots, the amplitude and the phase response of the system.

Now on the phase plot I want to add axes labels. So I tried:

```
AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Text[Frequentie[f]]], 
  HoldForm[Text[Fase[\[Degree]]]]
```

But that does not work. What can I do to add the text to the axes of the phase plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FrameLabel -> {{" ", " "}, {HoldForm[Text[Frequentie[f]]], 
   HoldForm[Text[Fase[\[Degree]]]]}}
```

or

```
FrameLabel -> {None, {HoldForm[Text[Frequentie[f]]], 
   HoldForm[Text[Fase[\[Degree]]]]}}
```

or...